# Opera Themes error when uploading a zip file

Tags: opera

I am looking to customize my browsers by uploading the addons on Opera Themes. I get an error: persona.ini is invalid. Please correct it and try uploading again. The parser reported: Invalid The Blues/persona.ini file, section Window Image not found. Please fix it and try again.

I have tried new Images in my file, but it is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

put persona.ini in the folder of extension,
in persona.ini write code

```
[Window Image]
Type            = BestFit
Tile Center     = "image.png"
Colorize        = 0
```

image.png put in the same folder